# Unable to set non-Latin website link for profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, hyperlinks, localization

Non-Latin website link is not acceptable for profile. E.g., I'm trying to set site the address to `http://россия.рф/`:

> [image: россия.рф]

After saving the changes I see a message that all saved succesfully:

> Your profile has been saved successfully.

But after refreshing the page I see the following:

> [image: result]

It seems that only dot symbol was accepted.

Comment: I opened that link and then asked Chrome to translate it to English ... that didn't help much ...

Comment: @rene because Google sucks on image translating

Comment: LOL, true that! Cheers! ;)

Comment: As a workaround, you should be able to run your Unicode domain name through http://idna-converter.com and use the Latin/Punycode domain name instead. For your particular example, it will return `xn--h1alffa9f.xn--p1ai`, and going to http://xn--h1alffa9f.xn--p1ai takes me to the same place as http://россия.рф

Comment: @JeffZeitlin yep. But it's ugly way.

Comment: You won't get an argument from me about that; just offering it as a workaround. I agree that on the StackExchange side, it should be considered a bug, and corrected.